# Ubuntu 12.04 jumps straight to bios when booting

Tags: 12.04, boot

So I tried installing Ubuntu 12.04 LTS onto my new machine, which i've just built and it worked just fine. I then swapped the mainboard and cpu with another pair of these to see the difference in power usage.

However with the new setup I couldn't even get the machine to boot, it jumped right into the bios and wouldn't from neither of my three hdds. So I then tried reinstalling Ubuntu completely from scratch and removed 2 the hdds, and installed it from my usb stick which i used before to the one left hdd. The installation gave me no error whatsoever, however the problem still remained. So I went further and read in another thread to install boot-repair to maybe fix a problem with the bootloader. This also worked just fine, when completed it said "any errors have been fixed" or something along those lines.

My Problem, however, still remains. I get now error message at all, so I'm asking, is there any place where I can find some kind of boot log to narrow down my problem?

Comment: Maybe there's something wrong with the bios configuration.

Comment: I'll give it a look. I put it in right from the box though.

Comment: It might also be a simple loose connection.

Comment: I doubt it's an hardware error. I tried reinstalling again and it prompted me with "You already have an Ubuntu installation on this drive. Do you want to erase the old one or install the new alongside the old one?" 


So it's definitely all there.